# Why broadband internet connection takes 5-6 minutes to get established?

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection, broadband

I have a broadband connection, which is being served via a D-Link Router. On the same system I have installed two operating systems, both windows 7, but one on SSD Drive and the other on normal hard drive.

When I open the windows 7 installed on SSD drive, I don't even wait for more than 10 seconds and I can see the connection in the right side of task bar, but when I boot up with windows 7 on normal hard drive, it takes more than 5-6 minutes to establish. I know, normal hard drive will be slow, but this much slow???

Is there any way to improve this connection establishment time?

Comment: It(connecting to the network) is probably in line with outer start up items. It could be at the end of the list. You may want to review what is starting up on the HDD Windows. SSD are faster to begin with, so start up programs are up and ready faster and the line up of start up items just gets going in less time.

Comment: There's a difference between seeing the icon and actually having network access. You probably already have access to the network and the taskbar is just still loading.